# Check SObjectType FLS for a specific user

Tags: apex, soap-api, security, field-level-security

I need to be able to check the FLS (Field-Level Security) settings for a specific user. Since the user in question will not be executing the check I cannot use the DescribeFieldResult class for the check.

Is this possible in Apex or using the Salesforce API?

Answer (score 4):

You can query the [FieldPermissions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm) object using the User's Profile as the ParentId field.

```
SELECT Id, Field, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions 
WHERE ParentId IN 
  (SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE ProfileId IN 
    (SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE DeveloperName = 'StandardUser')) 
AND SobjectType = 'Account'
```

Unfortunately this by itself won't take into account other PermissionSet's, so you may need to aggregate all the PermissionSets in addition to the Profile (which shouldn't be too difficult).

Comment: You cannot nest sub-selects. `WHERE Profile.DeveloperName = 'StandardUser'` should work in this case. Also, as a note, profiles have underlying PermissionSet records available in Apex/API which are distinguished from other permission sets by the field `IsOwnedByProfile`. [source](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html)

Comment: This does not return any cases where `PermissionsRead = false`